# Why is my Scalacheck/Scalatest PropertyCheckConfig being ignored?

Tags: scala, testing, scalatest, scalacheck

I have a project with a lot of Scalacheck generators that is getting a GeneratorDrivenPropertyCheckFailedException with the message "Gave up after 0 successful property evaluations. 2 evaluations were discarded."

I want to have it try to evaluate it many more times like 500 (the default) would be fine, but I'm not seeing my configuration override actually being used.

I added this code to the test class and I'm still getting the exact same message. I've tried 'sbt clean' just to make sure something weird wasn't happening there.

```
implicit override val generatorDrivenConfig = PropertyCheckConfig(minSuccessful = 1, maxDiscarded = 500, workers = 1)
```

Why is my Scalacheck/Scalatest PropertyCheckConfig being ignored?

I'm using Scalatest 2.2.1 with Scalacheck 1.12.1 with Scala 2.10.4

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you are filtering the generator (for instance, by using a `suchThat`), the generator can be creating a large number of values that don't satisfy your `suchThat` constraint and are therefore getting discarded. I've run into this when I constrain the length of strings. The one suggestion I can give you is to try and create your Gen a different way where you aren't discarding so many of them.

For example, here is what I first had for generating 4-character strings:

```
val gen4CharString = Gen.listOfN(4, (Gen.listOfN[Char] suchThat (s => s != "" && s.length == 4)))
```

This was causing too many generated values to be discarded, resulting in an error similar to the one you were seeing. Altering the generator like below eliminated the problem.

```
val gen4CharString = Gen.listOfN[Char] (4, Gen.alphaChar).map (_.mkString)
```

Comment: Extremely helpful tip. Ran into this problem generating strings of no greater than a certain length with `Gen.alphaNumStr.suchThat(_.length <= 50)` and resolved with `Gen.choose(0, 50).map(Gen.listOfN(_, Gen.alphaNumChar)).map(_.mkString)`.